# Open pushout stability

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, terminology

If a scheme $X$ (or any reasonable geometric object) is covered by two open subschemes $X_1$ and $X_2$, then we know how to describe morphisms with domain $X$. But we can also describe morphisms with codomain $X$: If $h : Y \to X$ is a morphism, then $Y$ is covered by the two open subschemes
$$Y_1 = h^{-1}(X_1),~ Y_2 = h^{-1}(X_2),$$
so that we get morphisms $h_1 : Y_1 \to X_1$, $h_2 : Y_2 \to X_2$, we have
$$Y_1 \cap Y_2 = h_1^{-1}(X_1 \cap X_2) = h_2^{-1}(X_1 \cap X_2),$$
and the two restricted morphisms
$$h_1|_{Y_1 \cap Y_2},h_2|_{Y_1 \cap Y_2} : Y_1 \cap Y_2 \to X_1 \cap X_2$$
coincide. Conversely, if $Y$ is covered by two open subschemes $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, two morphisms $h_1 : Y_1 \to X_1$, $h_2 : Y_2 \to X_2$ are given such that $Y_1 \cap Y_2 = h_1^{-1}(X_1 \cap X_2) = h_2^{-2}(X_1 \cap X_2)$ and the two restricted morphisms $h_1|_{Y_1 \cap Y_2},h_2|_{Y_1 \cap Y_2}  : Y_1 \cap Y_2 \to X_1 \cap X_2$ agree, then there is a unique morphism $h : Y \to X$ which induces $Y_1,Y_2,h_1,h_2$.

**Question.** What is the name of this gluing property? Is it an example of a canonical categorical notion?

I would like to call this "open pushout stability"

Edit: Since the notion of an [extensive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category) deals with such a statement for coproducts, perhaps **pushout-extensive category** would be a good term?

Comment: Related: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category

Comment: Isn't this simply the naturality of the pushout?

Comment: @SteveCostenoble: No. These statements are false in many categories of algebraic structures, where pushouts exist.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Indeed, I had a look at this page before asking here. :) At least, the notion of a stable coproduct is quite well-known.